# Several OpenLayers draw interactions at once

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a use case where I need to let multiple users to draw on selected areas of a map at the same time. Here's what I tried so far.
Created a map and added a button to select drawing areas. This part is not necessarily concurrent. Following is a part of the button click event.

```
var myVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector(
                    {
                        source: new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false})
                    });
//add layer to the map
map.addLayer(myVectorLayer);

//create a new interaction
var interaction1 = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: myVectorLayer.getSource(),
        type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ 'Polygon',
        freehand: true
});
map.addInteraction(interaction1);
```

Upon clicking that button each user gets his own vector layer to draw on and with the draw interaction he can choose the area he intends to work on.
After all the users selected the areas, they should be able to draw on their areas simultaneously. I display a tool box attached to each area and each tool box has a button which adds a draw interaction to the map. Heres the interaction.

```
var interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
             source: layer.getSource(),
             type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ 'Polygon',
             freehandCondition: function (evt) {
                    var coord = evt.coordinate;
                    var myArea = layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0];//area is the first feature of the layers feature collection
                    var y = myArea.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate(coord);
                    return ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys(evt) && y;
                    }
                });
```

The layer is the one user is working on. What the freehandCondition does is, get the first feature in the layer, which is the drawing area user selected, and return true if the browser event coordinate is inside that area. This works well if I draw shapes one by one. But when I do this for two areas on my touch device sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't. Has anyone tried to do this with openlayers? Is it even possible?